# Are ghasts actually from the overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

## Background

This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/cbh76k/okay_so_this_achievement_confirms_that_ghasts_are/) about the "Uneasy Alliance" achievement, got me thinking about the nature of ghasts:

[image]

## Question

In minecraft lore, did ghasts indeed originate from the overworld?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything on the wiki, I can't say for sure but I'm pretty sure they've never stated anything much about the history of ghasts. I think that the idea behind it is that Ghasts are like ghosts, and the Nether (where they are found) is like Hell, so someone lived (in the overworld), then died and became a ghost living in Hell, and when you bring them back they are returning to the overworld, where they are originally from.

Or as others have pointed out in comments, it's possibly referring to the overworld as *your* home (and assuming you don't live in an awesome nether fortress), this is more likely now that I think about it, although I wouldn't rule out my original explanation either.

But I don't think that canonically they are 'from' anywhere, they just spawn naturally. Minecraft doesn't really have lore is the thing.

Comment: I agree, they really don't have lore.  But this is official text from an achievement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just referring to the player's home, not the ghast's...

Comment: @SaintWacko It is plausible that 'home' means the player's home, but the key word would be 'rescue'. If ghasts lived in the nether it seems unlikely they would need to be rescued from there.

Comment: But why is killing it considered an "alliance"?